# Перегрузка операции == для классов

Tags: c++

не подскажите как правильно в данном случае нужно перегрузить оператор == для классов

```
class MError {
protected:
    char m_description[512];
public:
    void addLocation(const char* _where) {
        strcat(m_description, _where);
    }
 
    const char* getDescription() const { return m_description; }
};
class MEPrintValue :public MError {
public: MEPrintValue(const char* _where) {
    strcpy(m_description, "Исключение: вывод пустого массива.\n");
    addLocation(_where);
}
};
emplate <class T>
class TMatrix {
private:
    int n; // строки
    int m; // столбцы 
    T** matrix;
public:
void print(ostream& stream) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                // Исключение если выводит пустой массив  
                if ((matrix[i][j]) == -842150451) {
                    throw MEPrintValue("В TMatrix::print(ostream& stream)\n");
                }
                stream << matrix[i][j] << " ";
                stream << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
 
class Fractional {
private:
    int denominator; // знаменатель
    int numerator; // числитель
public:
bool operator == () const {
 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте подумаем, а что такое равенство в данном случае. Можно равенство на уровне значений, тогда это будет так

```
bool operator == (const Fractional & oth) const {
   return denominator == oth.denominator && numerator == oth.numerator;
}
```

Но этот код будет считать 1/2 и 2/4 - разными дробями. Но это легко исправить.

```
bool operator == (const Fractional & oth) const {
   return denominator * oth.numerator == oth.denominator * numerator;
}
```

(о переполнении умолчим, сами попробуйте придумать)